# Using the moving frame method to calculate the Gaussian Curvature of a Rotational Surface

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, surfaces

Let $h,g:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be differential functions with $h(s) > 0$ and $\alpha : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}^3$ a curve parameterized by arc length, $$\alpha(s) = \left(0, h(s), g(s)\right). $$
Consider the parametrized surface
$$x(s, \theta) = \left(h(s)\sin \theta, h(s)\cos \theta, g(s)\right).$$
I want to calculate the Gaussian Curvature of this surface using the moving frame method.

My purse is use the equation $d\omega_{12} = - K \omega_1 \wedge\omega_2$, where $\omega_{12}$ is one of the connection forms and $\omega_1, \omega_2$ are the coframe.

First, I took the filds $e_1:=\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}$ and $e_2:= \frac{1}{h}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}$ to be the frame. Now, how can I find out the coframe $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ associated?

Comment: Please edit your post to include what you've tried and ask a specific question where you get stuck. We do not do homework on order here. Moreover, before I can help, I need to know exactly the notation and structure equations you are using. There are a number of different possibilities.

Comment: The easiest thing to do is to find the metric (first fundamental form). Note that you'll have $e_1\cdot e_2=0$ and so the metric is $A^2\,ds\otimes ds + B^2\,d\theta\otimes d\theta$. Check that $\omega_1 = A\,ds$ and $\omega_2 = B\,d\theta$ are the dual coframe to your frame.